# free() 2D Arrays in C Using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, free

I would like to use free() to remove the whole matrix arrays from memory. How can i do it?

Allocate arrays:

```
// test.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define BYTE unsigned char
#define  my_array(n_height, n_width) (BYTE **)create_array(sizeof(BYTE), (n_height), (n_width))

char  **create_array(int u_size, int height, int width);
char  **create_array(int u_size, int height, int width)
{
    char  **array;
    int     i;

    if (!(array=(char **)malloc(height*sizeof(char *)))) {
        printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (!(array[0]=(char *)malloc(height*width*u_size))) {
        printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (i=1; i<height; i++)
        array[i] = array[i-1] + width*u_size;
    return array;
}
```

---

```
// test.c
#include "array.h"
int main()
{
    unsigned char *bytes;
    BYTE  **matrix;
    matrix = my_array(height, width);

    int c = 0;
    for (int h=0; h < height; h++) {
        for (int w=0; w < (width); w++) {
            matrix[h][w] = bytes[c];
            c++;
        }
    }

    printf("Done.\n");

    free(matrix); // really empty memory??
}
```

I am not sure whether matrix has been completely removed from the memory when i use free(matrix);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call `free()` exactly once per call to `malloc()`. You can't "fool" `free()` into free:ing several blocks. If you want to be able to call `free()` only once, you'll need to make sure to allocate all the required memory in a single call to `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `malloc`s, so you need two `free`s. But you can optimise a bit if you rearrange your allocation:

```
/...
void* mcontent;
if (!(mcontent = malloc(height*sizeof(char*) + height*width*u_size))) {
    printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
    exit(0);
}
array = (char **)mcontent;
array[0]=(char *)(mcontent + height*sizeof(char*));
```

This has two advantages. First, usability: you only have to free your matrix "object" without bothering how it was made. Second, efficiency: you have locality AND only one allocation, which both means speed.

Comment: Thank you! Your code is clear to me to understand how to use free() since i was struggling within the loop to free memory before. I got it now.

Comment: You should be using `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or `exit(1);` not `exit(0);` if dynamic memory allocation fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you like, you can use the beautiful C99 pointer-to-variable-length-array.

Allocate like this:

```
char (*arr)[width] = emalloc(width*height);
```

Index like this:

```
arr[23][10] = 2; //row 23, column 10
```

And free like this:

```
 free(arr);
```

Comment: @Alex `emalloc()` is the name used all over Plan9 for a `malloc()` that returns a valid pointer, or prints an error, and exits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the memory is freed, you should use the `Valgrind` program.
See [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)
In this case, try this:

```
free(matrix[0]);
free(matrix);
```

Comment: This is exactly the code i used before i post my question. I was not sure because i got the error on the line -> free(matrix[i]);
: test(830,0x7fff73cd4960) malloc: *** error for object 0x117439a4c: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(gdb)

Comment: It's correct, you only allocate twice, therefore you must free twice too. I recommend that you use the valgrind program, it's a great tool.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I got it now: for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {free(matrix[i]);} free(matrix); does not work in this case.